# ES6/TypeScript import and Angular

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, node-modules, es6-module-loader

There's something I'm not sure to understand with ES6 module import and Angular (although it's not restrcited to Angular)

When I'm importing a component like this :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

Ok I'm importing the Component class from @angular/core package.

But if I go to node_modules : there's no Component class file at the root of @angular/core.
I can see some bundle, esm5, esm2015 and src packages and also files like core.d.ts at the root.
How the module loader manages to understand where this Component is located ?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't specify a file name to import, `index.ts/js` will be used (@angular/core/index.ts). You can go from this file up the tree (there are many files that only export in between)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you importing `@angular/core` module, it will look for `package.json` in the module root that is `node_modules/@angular/core` folder.  And then look for `main` property which is the main entry point of the module. This is the file you want.

[image]

Comment: Ok than you. I can see that in package.json there's a main attribute (core.umd.js) and also a module attributre (core.js). Are they the same thing ?

Comment: @AntonBoarf There are different module coding pattern.  So their source code are different in module system only.